# How do append a CA to an SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, zimbra

I am trying to setup an SSL cert for a domain on my Zimbra server. When I go to the place where it wants to me to paste the certs into the borwser windows it pops up a little warning message that says.

[image: Domain Certificate should be appended with CA certificate, and Domain private key should be passwordless]

How do I append the CA to the domain cert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Export each part of the chain into x509 format, then jam them together in your favorite text-editor-that-won't-mess-with-things, the subject (your certificate) first, then its signer, with the root at the bottom of the file.  You'll end up with this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Your certificate's base64 data here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(intermediate certificate's base64 data here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(root certificate's base64 data here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

(By "text-editor-that-won't-mess-with-things" I mean no Word/Wordpad; `--` getting turned into `–` is a bad, bad thing.)

Comment: I get the idea of how to chain the cert together but for some reason Zimbra is not playing nice with my certs. I realize that is out of the scope this question.

Comment: Is the other part of the error a potential issue?  Is the private key DES-encrypted?

Comment: No I don't think it is DES encrypted, I exported the key private key from XCA in PEM format. I am going to ask the people on the Zimbra forums I am sure they would be able to point me to something to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the .pem files together with the CA being in the bottom and then work your way up towards the top of the text file for each next-level .pem file. The following from Cisco provides some very detailed steps that should be relevant - www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6366/products_configuration_example09186a0080a77597.shtml.